# Angular expression in javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can i use angular expression in function to pass certain value?

Question can i use regular javascript function or i must use only functions that i specified in My OptionControler?

```
my HTML HEAD
<script>
  function tvarURL(value){console.log(value)}
</script>
```

**my HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="OptionControler" >
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="grupe in grupes" ng-click="tvarURL(grupe.grupe)">
            {{grupe.grupe}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My OptionControler with JSON FILE **This is smaler version of json file**

```
    var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
    module.controller('OptionControler', ['$scope',
        function rodyti($scope) {



    $scope.grupes = [
    {
        "grupe": "MM4-1",
        "URL": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1BYBxGHSPEGNrV2jvJV_c6gJwRzkHwy0OL4avnk8O9S0/od6/public/values?alt=json",
        "fakultetas": "TKF",
        "tipas": "nuolatines",
        "kursas": "kursas1"
          },
    {
        "grupe": "MM4-2",
        "URL": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1FQmHYUpIt6GYxOKB63Smtk-6LBUiKUyCY_HTniGuR_M/od6/public/values?alt=json",
        "fakultetas": "TKF",
        "tipas": "Nuolatinės",
        "kursas": "kursas1"
          }
        ];       
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but remove the curly brackets.

```
ng-click="tvarURL(grupe.grupe)"
```

Comment: but function outputs undefiend and i dont know why
ng reapeat works just fine

Comment: @NatalijaMozuraitene are you trying to pass in the individual grupe? Just do tvarURL(grupe), not grupe.grupe.

Comment: If that doesn't work, give us more details in your original post. What does grupe look like? What is tvarURL?

Comment: ng-reapeat outputs grupe.grupe just fine and i have long list of names i want to click on individual name and output that name in console. Question where my function tvarURL must be? In controler or can i define it like regular javascript function?

Comment: It needs to be on the $scope in your controller, with the name tvarURL. So, $scope.tvarURL = function (value) {... Stuff here...}

Comment: @NatalijaMozuraitene thanks for the edit. Move the function from the head in the HTML to the scope in the controller as I directed in my previous comment. That should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to omit the `{{}}`

```
<li ng-repeat="grupe in grupes" ng-click="tvarURL(grupe.grupe)">
```